# Rspec tests reporting invalid pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a couple of tests which are reporting a pass where they would appear to fail:

```
1059:       describe "open second event" do
    1060:           before { find("div[data-event-no='1'] a[data-toggle='collapse']").click }
 => 1061:           it { binding.pry
    1062:               find("div[data-event-no='0'] a[data-toggle='collapse']").text == "More info..."}
    1063:           # it { find("div[data-event-no='0'] a[data-toggle='collapse']").text != "Less info..."}
    1064:           # it { find("div[data-event-no='1'] a[data-toggle='collapse']").text == "Less info..."}
    1065:           # it { find("div[data-event-no='1'] a[data-toggle='collapse']").text != "More info..."}
    1066:           it { should have_content(venue.events[1].description)}

[11] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4::Nested_6::Nested_1>)> find("div[data-event-no='0'] a[data-toggle='collapse']").text
=> "Less info..."
[12] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4::Nested_6::Nested_1>)> find("div[data-event-no='0'] a[data-toggle='collapse']").text == "More info..."
=> false
[13] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4::Nested_6::Nested_1>)> e
.

Finished in 3 minutes 21.05 seconds
1 example, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 0

Coverage report generated for RSpec to /Users/richardbox/Dropbox/Rails/kc/kangodo/coverage. 537 / 1260 LOC (42.62%) covered.
```

Note also that I an running with js:true set.

I am expecting the test at line 1061/2 to fail, indeed where I enter copy/paste the statement in the test into the console, the response is false, but the outcome is a test pass.

Why is this failing in the console, but passing the test? Is there a better way to write the test?

The generated html of the relevant section is as follows:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
find("div[data-event-no='0'] a[data-toggle='collapse']").text.should == "More info..."
```

or

```
expect(find("div[data-event-no='0'] a[data-toggle='collapse']").text).to eql "More info..."
```

As it stands your test is not making an assertion, its just evaluating a boolean expression.

Comment: Thanks @Steve. Of course.... but the first solution I think has the methods the wrong way around?.. It should be: `find("div[data-event-no='0'] a[data-toggle='collapse']").text.should == "More info..."`

Comment: thats true, I'll fix that

Comment: `should` style assertions are being phased out in favour of `expect` style so the second solution is a bit more up to date.